# Xamarin integration with smart lights?

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-home, google-smart-home

I am trying to see if there is any way to interact with smart lights using Xamarin, I found one way to use philips' APi but I want to see what I had in mind is possible. Is it possible to connect to a google home thats already connected to smart lights and pass arguements through Google home to the smart lights? Because for some of the smart lights, they dont have readily available APIs for general public, so thats the only possiblity I had in my head and I'm not too sure how to approach this issue or whether or not its even possible.

Comment: You mention Philips Hue (afaik that's the only smartlight Philips produces), but is that the brand you want to interact with, or was it just an example?

Comment: @Falgantil its just an example as I'm trying to experiment with Globe Smart lights, but using an existing google home with smart lights integrated already would make the process easier and it would make it universal with all smart lights that google would support

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to connect to a google home thats already connected to smart lights and pass arguments through Google home to the smart lights?

The Smart Home API does not have support for this. Devices linked to a user's account are stored in [Home Graph](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/concepts/homegraph), but authenticated access to data in Home Graph is not currently supported on a user level. Applications can only access the devices that are provided to Google by their own integration.